# Change Google Map Offset Center

Tags: android, google-maps, offset

I'm trying to set the user location on the map such that it sits about 1/3 of the way up from the bottom of the screen, and when the map rotates, it will rotate around this point.

The closest I've got to achieving this is by using the `setPadding()` method, however, this causes the map to sort of shake when rotated, as the center point sort of 'floats' around where it actually should be. It looks quite ugly

```
int mapHeight = mapView.getHeight();
googleMap.setPadding(0, mapHeight / 5, 0, 0);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**: Explained in picture below

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41469392/lock-google-maps-on-users-location/41618422#41618422

Comment: I don't see how that answer will allow me to lock the users location to a spot other than in the center of the map.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better what you are trying to do? Maybe an image...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't need paddings

Change mappoint X and Y values as you need you can call this where you want! may be inside your `onLocationChanged` like  `changeOffsetCenter(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());`

```
 public void changeOffsetCenter(double latitude,double longitude) {
            Point mappoint = mGoogleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
            mappoint.set(mappoint.x, mappoint.y-100); // change these values as you need , just hard coded a value if you want you can give it based on a ratio like using DisplayMetrics  as well
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mGoogleMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(mappoint)));
        }
```

output :

[image]

Comment: @ZeroOne your question is not clear elaborate please? you can have one center point is that what you are asking ?

Comment: basically, how to do it for multiple marker which is re-position them at bottom of map?

Comment: Friend this answer is for a center point not center points you may do that by selecting a main marker at your bottom with a law zoom level(cam is not that zoomed) or go with a solution like where you take center point(LatLng) between some locations and keep it as the center possition.Check this  might help > http://stackoverflow.com/a/35646210/5188159 finding a position is not related to this answer but move center point as  you want(using x,y) is the one which i addressed here :)

Comment: I prefer this : mMap.setPadding(leftPx, topPx, rightPx, bottomPx); >>https://stackoverflow.com/a/20671939/929086

Comment: Instead of using `Point.set()` to set a new value you can use `Point.offset(xOfffset, yOffset)` to add an offset for the point

Comment: this will cause inaccurate positions when you try to navigate from distant points, not to mention that it will not unless you animate the camera.

Answer (score 1):

Google map v3 beta seems to fix it, using padding now properly move pivotX/pivotY for rotation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/v3-client-migration

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer might be work of "animateCamera". Its makes "shaking of rotations" almost invisible. So more easy will be using

mMap.setPadding(leftPx, topPx, rightPx, bottomPx)

with mMap.animateCamera
or twice mMap.moveCamera(in case of changing bearing
1nd moveCamera rotate with center of device, 2nd moveCamera make correct center using padding)

Its kind of hack, while google do not fix rotation considering setPadding